# AJAX - Sending knockout observables as JSON object to server using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js

I am trying to send form fields which are bound to particular observable to my server in the form of JSON object but I receive empty JSON string at server side. I do not want to send the entire view model to accomplish this task.
this is the javascript i have so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new AddSubjectKo());
});



  function AddSubjectKo()
  {
    var self=this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.quiz = ko.observable();
    self.ass = ko.observable();
    self.oht = ko.observable();
    self.sess = ko.observable();
    self.ese = ko.observable();
    self.SubjectAdded=function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/courses",
            type: "post",
            data: formToJSON(),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data){
           alert("success");
             },
          error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert("failure");
             }   
       });  
        function formToJSON() {
            alert(self.name());
               return JSON.stringify({
                   "name": self.name,
                   "quiz": self.quiz,
                   "ass": self.ass,
                   "oht": self.oht,
                   "sess": self.sess,
                   "ese": self.ese,
                    });
           }
        }
      //$("#alert").slideDown();

  }
```

Comment: You just need to use parenthesis

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't know what observables are, it sees them as ordinary functions, which cannot be meaningfully stringified. Pass *the values of those observables* into `JSON.stringify` instead, like you're doing in `alert()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ko.toJSON` function for this:

```
  function AddSubjectKo()
  {
    var self=this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.quiz = ko.observable();
    self.ass = ko.observable();
    self.oht = ko.observable();
    self.sess = ko.observable();
    self.ese = ko.observable();
    self.SubjectAdded=function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/courses",
            type: "post",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
             },
             error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("failure");
             }   
       });  
   }
```

Comment: The ko.toJSON function solved the problem. However, i specified in the question that I do not need to pass the entire the entire view model but by passing self to ko.toJSON function, you are indeed doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use call the observable (add parenthesis) to grab the values in the observables:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new AddSubjectKo());
});



  function AddSubjectKo()
  {
    var self=this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.quiz = ko.observable();
    self.ass = ko.observable();
    self.oht = ko.observable();
    self.sess = ko.observable();
    self.ese = ko.observable();
    self.SubjectAdded=function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/courses",
            type: "post",
            data: formToJSON(),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data){
           alert("success");
             },
          error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert("failure");
             }   
       });  
        function formToJSON() {
            alert(self.name());
               return JSON.stringify({
                   "name": self.name(),
                   "quiz": self.quiz(),
                   "ass": self.ass(),
                   "oht": self.oht(),
                   "sess": self.sess(),
                   "ese": self.ese(),
                    });
           }
        }
      //$("#alert").slideDown();

  }
```