# How to insert knockout generated JSON data in the mySql table?

Tags: php, json, mysqli, knockout.js

I have a simple form that generates a `JSON` format of the `'brand name'` input box. I've used `knockout.js` to generate the `JSON` from the form. Now, how  can give this generated data to `php` action file to insert this `JSON` data in my `mySql` table named `'b_names'` in the field `'brand_name'` using `php`?

This is my form:

```
<button data-bind='click: addBrandName'>Add a drug</button>
<form action="php/action.php">
   <table data-bind="foreach: brandNames">
      <tbody >
         <td>
            <label>Brand name</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind='value: brandName'>
         </td>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<p>
   <button data-bind='click: save, enable: brandNames().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
</p>
<div>
   <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='10' cols='33'> 
   </textarea>
</div>
```

This is the script:

```
<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
   var initialData = [
   ];

   var brandNamesModel = function(brandNames) {
   var self = this;
   self.brandNames = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(brandNames, function(drug) {
       return { 
           brandName: drug.brandName };
   }));

   self.addBrandName = function() {
       self.brandNames.push({
           brandName: ""
       });
   };

   self.save = function() {
       self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.brandNames), null, 2));
   };

   self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
   };

   ko.applyBindings(new brandNamesModel(initialData));        
   });
</script>
```

I was trying this php action and surely it's not working.

```
$dbCon = mysqli_connect(localhost, $user, $password, $database) 
        or die ("error connecting database");
echo "Connected";

$data = file_get_contents($lastSavedJson);
$arrat = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($array as $row)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO b_name(brand_name) VALUES('".$row["brandName"]."')";
    mysqli_query($bdCon, $sql);
};
```

I'm trying to understand it so, any help would be appreciated.
Without the php here is the working fiddle of the form- 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/0agajy4h/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the best help from the blog of [Wern Ancheta](http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2012/12/26/building-a-registration-system-with-knockoutjs/). It is a great article and he explains all the codes there.

Here is his version of how he does the job that I've been looking for:

The `html` and `knockout` code:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="load: loadData()">
    <div class="new_student">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="name" data-bind="value: person_name, hasfocus: person_name_focus"/>
        <input type="text" class="age" placeholder="age" data-bind="value: person_age"/>

        <button data-bind="click: createPerson">Create</button>     
    </div>

    <table data-bind="visible: people().length > 0" class="students">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: name, click: nameUpdating, visible: !nameUpdate()"></span>
                    <input type="text" class="name" data-bind="value: name, visible: nameUpdate, hasfocus: nameUpdate">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: age, click: ageUpdating, visible: !ageUpdate()"></span>
                    <input type="text" class="age" data-bind="value: age, visible: ageUpdate, hasfocus: ageUpdate">
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removePerson">remove</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.updatePerson">update</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    

    <button data-bind="click: echoPerson">echo</button>
</div>




<script>
var personModel = function(id, name, age){
    var self = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.age = ko.observable(age);

    this.nameUpdate = ko.observable(false);
    this.ageUpdate = ko.observable(false);

    this.nameUpdating = function(){
        self.nameUpdate(true);
    };
    this.ageUpdating = function(){
        self.ageUpdate(true);
    };

};

var model = function(){

    var self = this;
    this.person_name = ko.observable("");
    this.person_age = ko.observable("");
    this.people = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.person_name_focus = ko.observable(true);

    this.createPerson = function(){
        if(self.validatePerson()){

            var person = {'name' : this.person_name(), 'age' : this.person_age()};

            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'refresher_save.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'student' : person, 'action' : 'insert'},
                    success: function(id){
                        console.log(this);
                        self.people.push(new personModel(id, self.person_name(), self.person_age()));
                        self.person_name("");
                        self.person_age("");
                    }
                }
            );          

        }else{
            alert("Name and age are required and age should be a number!");
        }
    };

    this.validatePerson = function(){
        if(self.person_name() !== "" && self.person_age() != "" && Number(self.person_age()) + 0 == self.person_age()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    this.removePerson = function(person){

        $.post(
            'refresher_save.php', 
            {'action' : 'delete', 'student_id' : person.id()}, 
            function(response){

                self.people.remove(person);
            }
        );
    };


    this.updatePerson = function(person){
        var id = person.id();
        var name = person.name();
        var age = person.age();

        var student = {'id' : id, 'name' : name, 'age' : age};
        $.post(
            'refresher_save.php', 
            {'action' : 'update', 'student' : student}

        );
    };

    this.loadData = function(){
        //fetch existing data from database

        $.ajax({
            url : 'refresher_save.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){


                for(var x in data){
                    var id = data[x]['id']
                    var name = data[x]['name'];
                    var age = data[x]['age'];
                    self.people.push(new personModel(id, name, age));
                }

            }
        });
        /*
        note: nothing would actually show up in the success function if the
        data that was returned from the server isn't a json string
        */
    };


    this.echoPerson = function(){
        console.log(ko.toJS(self.people()));
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(new model());
</script>
```

The server side `php` to `connect`, `insert`, `update` and `delete` data is:

```
<?php
$db = new MySqli('localhost', 'ashonko', '', 'tutorials');

$action = (!empty($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : '';
$student = (!empty($_POST['student'])) ? $_POST['student'] : '';


if(!empty($student)){
    $name = $student['name'];
    $age = $student['age']; 
}

switch($action){

    case 'insert':

        $db->query("INSERT INTO students SET name = '$name', age = '$age'"); 
        echo $db->insert_id; //last insert id
    break;

    case 'update':

        $id = $student['id'];
        $db->query("UPDATE students SET name = '$name', age = '$age' WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;

    case 'delete':

        $id = $_POST['student_id'];
        $db->query("UPDATE students SET status = 0 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;

    default:
        $students = $db->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE status = 1");
        $students_r = array();
        while($row = $students->fetch_array()){

            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $age = $row['age'];
            $name_update = false;
            $age_update = false;
            $name_focus = false;
            $age_focus = false;

            $students_r[] = array(
                'id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'age' => $age, 
                'nameUpdate' => $name_update, 'ageUpdate' => $age_update,
                'nameHasFocus' => $name_focus, 'ageHasFocus' => $age_focus
                ); 
        }

        echo json_encode($students_r);
    break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try ajax call like in this way

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "your api url",
        type: "post",
        data: ko.toJSON(self),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert("success");
         },
         error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("failure");
         }   
   });
```

In your php you should check data is coming or not in php file like below & on your browser console. Check data is coming that you sent in console.

```
print_r($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: Yes, I want to save this (or anything else according to the input) in the table named 'b_names' in the field 'brand_name'.

Comment: Thanks but, it returns an error: 
`Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty`

Comment: your data is not coming in your php file. can you use ajax call for this. if you say i can send you ajax call how to send data to php in json.

Comment: That would be really helpful if you can guide me how can I get this json data from the form to the php file in the context of my form.

Comment: in your php not issue the data you are sending form your file is not coming here in php kindly first check your call if data come then try you are not sending data correctly form knockout.js . one error in your php i found is $arrat it should be $array foreach loop

Comment: Thanks but can you help me where I might be wrong from sending the data?

Comment: your form is not sending the data properly in php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906365/ajax-sending-knockout-observables-as-json-object-to-server-using-ajax user this link how he is send the data form knockjs

Comment: Okay, I'm on it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if your problem solved kindly vote up and tell me for more help

Comment: Sure, I'll. Let me check it first. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: data is coming or not?